# Issues uploading files to server with phonegap cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have a very simple app that uploads pictures from camera and library. I managed to get it working as intended and for some reason unknown to me it stopped working. I even downloaded the files from a commit i'm sure it was working and it doesn't anymore.

The app let's you take a picture, choose one from the gallery, it then adds a little thumbnail (this is working) of the picture taken/selected and let's you submit a form. The upload happens right after you select the file and the form submit sends an email with those files as attachments (done on server).

The upload function always returns "An error has occurred: Code = 1"

EDIT: i'm testing the app by connecting my device to the phonegap windows server.

**EDIT2: apparently the problem was the phonegap emulator, tried on a real apk installation and it worked.**

CODE:

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
  //
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  // device APIs are available
  //
  function onDeviceReady() {
      // Now safe to use device APIs
      //alert("Device Ready");
      /*button that opens camera and takes picture*/
      $("#add_photo").click(function(){
          navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
          sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });
      });

      /*on success show thumbnail and try to upload*/
      function onSuccess(imageURI) {
          $("#preview").append("<img src='"+imageURI+"'/>");
          fileUpload(imageURI, "image/jpeg");
      }

      function onFail(message) {
          alert('Failed because: ' + message);
      }

      function fileUpload(imageURI, mimeType){
        var win = function (r) {
            console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
            console.log("Response = " + r.response);
            console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
            $('#form_submit').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#form_submit').prop('value', 'ENVIAR');
            //alert("done");
            //alert(r.response);
        }
        var fail = function (error) {
            alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
            console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
            console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
        }
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        options.mimeType = mimeType;
        var params = {};
        i++;
        sent_files[i] = session_id+"-"+i+"."+imageURI.split('.').pop();
        params.session_id = sent_files[i];
        $('[name=send]').val(sent_files.join());
        options.params = params;
        $('#form_submit').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#form_submit').prop('value', 'CARGANDO');
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://myServer/folder"), win, fail, options);
      };
  }
```

Comment: tried it on a real device instalation instead of using the phonegap emulator and it worked as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it on a real device instalation instead of using the phonegap windows server emulator and it worked as intended.

Silly me.